# Проблемы работы postgresql под wsl

Tags: php, postgresql, nginx, php-fpm, wsl

Пытаюсь настроить связку nginx+php-fpm+postgresql под wsl. nginx и php настроены и работают через tcp, а вот с postgre никак не выходит. При попытке запуска такого кода 
`$connect = new \PDO('pgsql:host=localhost:5432;dbname=test_database','test_user','qwerty');` сервер падает с 500 ошибкой. В логах nginx такие записи

```
Stack trace:
#0 /mnt/d/projects/../index.php(12): PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=loca...', 'test_user', 'qwerty')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /mnt/d/projects/BattleShipBackend/index.php on line 12" while reading response header from upstream, client: ::1, server: ttrss.*, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost:8080"
2018/11/27 16:42:34 [info] 18666#18666: *14 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: ::1, server: [::]:8080
2018/11/27 16:42:34 [info] 18666#18666: *13 client ::1 closed keepalive connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам же отвечаю на свой вопрос. Дело в том, что когда мы создаем новый объект PDO мы не можем писать рядом ip и через двоеточие порт. Порт для соединения с БД нужно писать в другом параметре(если он не стандартный для этой БД). WSL тут абсолютно не причем, как я изначально думал. Ошибка глупая, но ушло много времени чтобы найти проблему, может кому пригодится.